# Match a file name that doesn't contain substring using minimatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, minimatch

How can it be possible to match a filename like this

- filename.1.2.3.nupkg

without matching another one in the same directory that is like this

- filename.1.2.3.symbols.nupkg

I want to exclude the files that contain the substring ".symbols". The version of number of the file (1.2.3) might be different every time.

I need to use minimatch for this. https://realguess.net/tags/minimatch/

Answer (score 0):

This does it.

```
**/*[!symbols].nupkg
```

Comment: This will also exclude filename.1.2.3.nupkg. Basically any filename with two or more dots in it.

Any way to include the files with multiple dots?

Comment: You might have something different. It works for me. It excludes whatever has "symbols" in the name